# script does not stop when arguments are passed

Tags: bash

I have the following which works perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

killall java
#program USB
make iris install.1 mib510,/dev/ttyUSB0
#listen serial port and write to file
java net.tinyos.tools.PrintfClient -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB1:iris > foo.txt &
sleep 2
#if "Erase done" is printed to file, stop
if tail -f foo.txt | grep -n "Erase done" -q; then echo "Write ok";fi
killall java
```

But when I change my script to receive arguments below (`sh test.sh USB0 USB1 foo.txt`), it does not end. Although it writes the file, the process does not end

```
#!/bin/bash

killall java
#program USB
make iris install.1 mib510,/dev/tty$1
#listen serial port and write to file
java net.tinyos.tools.PrintfClient -comm serial@/dev/tty$2:iris > $3 &
sleep 2
#if "Erase done" is printed to file, stop
if tail -f $3 | grep -n "Erase done" -q; then echo "Write ok";fi
killall java
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: ./script.sh arg1 arg2 arg3. And i don't see you are using arg2

Comment: USB1 is my second argument

Comment: @SandyElms `$2` is in the argument to the `-comm` option.

Comment: Invoke your arguments in ""

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no success.

Comment: `tail -f` isn't going to exit until you tell it to (via ^C or `kill`) or the `grep` on the other side of the pipeline goes away. I suspect your first script seeming to work is a product of the target string appearing early in the output for some reason, while the string is getting caught somewhere in the pipe buffer at other times...

Comment: Interesting, I guess I'm going to have to modify the java code to get to my solution. Thank you once again

Comment: you might want to construct the arguments you want to pass to `java` as an array and then pass it as `java ... ${COMM[@]}` where, for example: `COMM=("--comm serial@/dev/tty${2}:iris")`

Answer (score 1):

It appears tail -f will quit when grep quits. So the problem might be with:

```
if tail -f $3 | grep -n "Erase done" -q; then echo "Write ok";fi
```

You can replace it with the following:

```
tail -f $3 | while read LOGLINE
do
   [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Erase done"* ]] && echo "Write ok" && pkill -P $$ tail
done
```